# Multiple route configuration does not work for PUT and Delete action in web api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, postman

I have configured the following route configuration in `WebApiConfig` file to call the web api controller method by actual method(action) name as well as default calling pattern.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {

        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream"));

        //By specifying action name 

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApiWithAction",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        // Default calling pattern

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { action = "DefaultAction", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

    }
}
```

following is the controller

```
public class TestController
{
    List<int> _lst;

    [ActionName("DefaultAction")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        _lst = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        return ToJson(_lst);
    }

    [ActionName("DefaultAction")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post(int id)
    {
        _lst.Add(id);
        return ToJson(1);
    }

    [ActionName("DefaultAction")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Put(int id)
    {
       //doing sothing
        return ToJson(1);
    }

    [ActionName("DefaultAction")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Delete(int id)
    {
        //doing sothing
        return ToJson(1);
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage Save(int id)
    {
        //doing sothing
        return ToJson(1);
    }

    private HttpResponseMessage ToJson(dynamic obj)
    {
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        response.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        return response;
    }
}
```

Calling the webapi controller `Post` or 'Get' method with below url is working fine resulting as expected.

POST -> http://localhost:56114/api/Test/

GET  -> http://localhost:56114/api/Test/

Calling the webapi controller `Save` method with below url is also working fine resulting as expected.

POST -> http://localhost:56114/api/Test/Save/1

but when I call the PUT or DELETE method of api controller by below given url it does not call the any of the (PUT/DELETE) method

PUT -> http://localhost:56114/api/Test/3

DELETE -> http://localhost:56114/api/Test/4

it gives following error message

```
{
    "Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:56114/api/Test/3'.",
    "MessageDetail": "No action was found on the controller 'Test' that matches the name '3'."
}
```

can anyone help me on this why PUT and DELETE method are not getting called by default URL pattern.

I want to call all my above metods by using following URL pattern

```
POST -> http://localhost:56114/api/Test/   -> should call Post
GET -> http://localhost:56114/api/Test/    -> should call Get
PUT -> http://localhost:56114/api/Test/3   -> should call Put 
DELETE -> http://localhost:56114/api/Test/4  -> should call Delete
POST -> http://localhost:56114/api/Test/Save/1  -> should call Save
```

Comment: The issue is the parameter name: `int value` if you rename them to `int id` then it'll probably work or add the attribute above your methods in question: `[Route("{value:int}]` also, what is `[ActionName]` being used for? is that from mvc and not webapi, you should use `RouteAttribute` instead.

Comment: Thanks @Ric, I have changed the 'int value' to 'int id' and  [ActionName("DefaultAction")] to [RouteAttribute("DefaultAction")] and defaults: new { action = "DefaultAction", id = RouteParameter.Optional } to defaults: new { Name = "DefaultAction", id = RouteParameter.Optional } but it is still not working, even now is I call method by "Post" it always calls "public HttpResponseMessage Save(int id)" method only.

Comment: remove the `[ActionName("DefaultAction")]` from your methods then call them.

Comment: @Ric, you mean to say remove [RouteAttribute("DefaultAction")] as I  have replace all [ActionName("DefaultAction")] with [RouteAttribute("DefaultAction")] ?

Comment: You don't really need them in your example, it might be worth adding `[HttpPost]`, `[HttpPut]` above your method signatures for clarity. But unless your method names are drastically different from what you want to call, there's no real reason to have them.

Comment: @Ric, ok you are saying instead of having core methods like  'GET , POST, PUT or DELETE' in controller! have specific method name with respective action attribute [HttpPost], [HttpPut] or [HttpDelete] is it?

Comment: Added an answer for more clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting to an answer.

I think the `ActionNameAtrribute` you are using is from MVC, not web api, so remove it, it wont do anything in this case.

Here is what I believe should work for you:

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
    _lst = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    return ToJson(_lst);
}

[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Post(int id)
{
    _lst.Add(id);
    return ToJson(1);
}

[HttpPut]
public HttpResponseMessage Put(int id)
{
    //doing sothing
    return ToJson(1);
}

[HttpDelete]
public HttpResponseMessage Delete(int id)
{
    //doing sothing
    return ToJson(1);
}

[HttpPost, Route("~/api/tests/save/{id}")]
public HttpResponseMessage Save(int id)
{
    //doing sothing
    return ToJson(1);
}
```

webapiconfig.cs:

```
 config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApiWithAction",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

The following patterns should now work, note that I've amended your first `post` call as the parameter `id` is present.

```
POST -> http://localhost:56114/api/Test/1   -> should call Post
GET -> http://localhost:56114/api/Test/    -> should call Get
PUT -> http://localhost:56114/api/Test/3   -> should call Put 
DELETE -> http://localhost:56114/api/Test/4  -> should call Delete
POST -> http://localhost:56114/api/Test/Save/1  -> should call Save
```

Your default routing is still applied as well as the more specific `api/{controller}/{action}/{id}` route.

Comment: do I need to change any thing on WebApiConfig file ? it is as is in development shown in example.

Comment: Shouldn't do, have you tested it?

Comment: this is only working POST -> localhost:56114/api/Test/Save/1 all other now giving same error as shown in my example

Comment: please try now.

Comment: thanks @Ric, I am out of office now, dev access is restricted, will try tomorrow and let you know..

Comment: @NeerajKumarGupta no worries!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the request paths to PUT and DELETE are matching the route template for "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}". Even though the request paths can match either defined route template, the template that was registered with "MapHttpRoute()" first will take priority. Here is how the PUT and DELETE request paths are being interpreted by the routing:

PUT: /api/Test/3 -> /api/<controller>/<action>

DELETE: /api/Test/4 -> /api/<controller>/<action>

With an optional "id" value that has been omitted in this case.

You could potentially solve this by switching the registration order of the routes, though it could affect other routing that you haven't listed here. Alternatively you could explicitly add the target action to the request path as such:

PUT: /api/Test/DefaultAction/3 -> /api/<controller>/<action>/<id>

DELETE: /api/Test/DefaultAction/4 -> /api/<controller>/<action>/<id>

Your requests to GET and POST are working due to the fact that the paths match the second route template with both an optional "action" and "id" parameter. The usage of an "id" in the PUT and DELETE commands causes the request paths to match the first route template instead.

I'm also not exactly sure why the "Save" action was successfully called in your example (unless you have a controller called "SaveController" that you did not show here). According to your routing logic that path would be interpreted as:

/api/Save/1 -> /api/<controller>/<action>

So the "Save" method in "TestController" is not actually being called by this request.

Comment: thanks @Matthew, I have corrected the "Save" method calling URL it was typo. Matthew can you please give me correct way to implement this functionality in webapi2, my requirement is the default method like 'GET , POST, PUT & DELETE' should work with default URL routing and specific method should work with url with specific action name. I have updated my question from which URL what I want to call check last statement of my question.

Comment: Try reordering the routing code blocks in the "WebApiConfig" class so that the block with the "//By specifying action name" comment appears below the block with the "// Default calling pattern" comment. That might be enough to accomplish what you want in the context of this example.